# How to pick a static group id?

Tags: group, gid

I am tasked with reassigning a static group id (gid) to an existing group name that exists on multiple Linux servers.

E.g. the group name `foo` currently exists on multiple servers, but with different gids:

```
$ ssh server-1
$ getent group foo
foo:x:998:user1,user2
```

```
$ ssh server-2
$ getent group foo
foo:x:999:user2,user3
```

...given the above, my task would be to assign a new, unique gid to the group name `foo` on server-1 and server-2.

I've found the following articles that describe changing an existing GID:

1. https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-correctly-change-the-uid-and-gid-of-a-user-group-in-linux/
2. [Change gid of a specific group](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33844/change-gid-of-a-specific-group)

**Question: how can I determine a "safe" number to use as the new gid?**

E.g. what is a clean/efficient/correct way to determine that the new gid I choose isn't already used on any of the PCs where this change needs to be applied?
Please also advise if there are other factors/considerations on picking a good/available/safe gid.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a one-off, I would not spend a lot of time on optimizing the process. First consideration is that I would choose a gid larger that 1000. Look at [reserved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_identifier#Reserved_ranges) gids for guidance. Again, as a one-off I would run something like

```
for host in (server1, server2, ..., serverx)
do
    ssh $host grep 1000 /etc/group
done
```

If any of the `grep`s return anything, increment the gid and try again. You can loop over ever-increasing gid's and check exit status if you really have a large number of servers or assigned groups to check. Your choice on whether to spend time on optimization or spend time running the loops manually.

Answer (score 2):

here is what is in `/etc/login.defs` taken from a RHEL 7.9 system for your reference

```
# Min/max values for automatic uid selection in useradd
#
UID_MIN                   1000
UID_MAX                 600000
# System accounts
SYS_UID_MIN               201
SYS_UID_MAX               999

#
# Min/max values for automatic gid selection in groupadd
#
GID_MIN                  1000
GID_MAX                 60000
# System accounts
SYS_GID_MIN               201
SYS_GID_MAX               999
```

for groups, the convention like was mentioned was typically above 1000.  But you or anyone can customize, so it is prudent to reference `/etc/login.defs`

Software installs like `clamav` or `intel oneapi` will create a *system* group and start at SYS_GID_MAX and work backward I believe.

My personal preference, as an admin, is to work with group id's between 1000-2000 for admin related stuff and then above 2000 for other miscellaneous user kinda group stuff.

- Any *really* safe gid would be between the `GID_MIN` and `GID_MAX` range.
- And still a relatively safe range is between `SYS_GID_MIN` and `SYS_GID_MAX`.
- Any safe gid is technically a number not already in use above `SYS_GID_MIN`.
- You don't want to choose anything below `SYS_GID_MIN` and definitely not below 100.